# Is there a second play through in Majora's Mask 3DS like there was in Ocarina of Time 3DS?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d

In the OoT remake you could play the master quest version after the first play through. Is there anything similar to this in the recent Majora's Mask remake? Basically the reason I am asking is because this kind of incentivizes you to wait to do a lot of the completionist type stuff until the second play through. If there is no post game then I will just do all the completionist stuff on this first play through. Is there any reason to wait?

Comment: I don't think so, but I also haven't completed the game to find out.  Bear in mind that the "second quest" stuff in Ocarina in Time 3DS was the GC Master Quest dungeons, which were originally produced for the Zelda N64DD (Disk Drive) game that got scrapped... its other assets ended up being used in Majora's Mask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they haven't included any sort of harder mode in Majora's Mask 3D.

[Ocarina of Time Master Quest](http://zeldawiki.org/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time_Master_Quest) already existed prior to the 3DS remake, so they choose to include it as a bonus. Majora's Mask 3DS includes [a slew of changes](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-majoras-mask/Version_Differences) to the main game, but sadly no "hard mode" of any kind.

Comment: I think though that adding a simple "Hero mode" where you take double damage would have been easy. Pity they didn't.

Answer (score 0):

No, sadly, I have 100% Majora's Mask 3d, with all the bomber note quests, heart pieces, and all 24 masks, and I had not gotten any acknowledgement of getting a master quest option, because I started a file for a 3-Heart run.

Comment: Thanks. I can also attest to not unlocking it after beating the game but if you have 100%ed it then that should be definitive.